# 12.04- Help? Unlocking Computer

Tags: unity, cinnamon

I uninstalled Cinnamon because I felt more comfortable with unity and when I close my lid, it goes into suspend ready for me to do my password to unlock the computer, now that cinnamon is gone, I get no response from doing Ctrl + Alt + L

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the log in screen there should be gear(menu) button that opens a drop down menu. You should be able to pick your "flavor" from there.